# no error validation if value no fit to regex

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, data-annotations

I'm using this regex in EF Data Annotations and in case the value is invalid the user is not getting any error, just non submitted form.
this is the code :

```
[Display(Name = "Phone number")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "number")]
[RegularExpression(@"^0(([57]\d)|[23489])\s*-?\s*[2-9]\d{6}$", ErrorMessage = "Not valid phone ")]
public int PhoneNumber { get; set; }
```

View

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new
{
    @class = "form-control  text-right",
    // @pattern = @"^0(([57]\d)|[23489])\s*-?\s*[2-9]\d{6}$",
    //@title = "not valid",
    @placeholder = @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.PhoneNumber),
    required = "required"
} })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

What is wrong here ?

```
<input name="PhoneNumber" class="form-control  text-right text-box single-line" id="PhoneNumber" required="required" type="number" placeholder="Phone number" value="" data-val-required="number" data-val="true" data-val-regex-pattern="^0(([57]\d)|[23489])\s*-?\s*[2-9]\d{6}$" data-val-regex="Not valid phone " data-val-number="The field Phone number must be a number.">
```

Comment: Your regex appears to allow white space - how can this possibly work for `int`? Show the actual html that is generated.

Comment: <input name="PhoneNumber" class="form-control  text-right text-box single-line" id="PhoneNumber" required="required" type="number" placeholder="Phone number" value="" data-val-required="number" data-val="true" data-val-regex-pattern="^0(([57]\d)|[23489])\s*-?\s*[2-9]\d{6}$" data-val-regex="Not valid phone " data-val-number="The field Phone number must be a number.">

Comment: this is my regex  needed format ..https://regex101.com/r/dS6gG4/1

Comment: Your property cannot be `int` if your allowing whitespace. It needs to be `string`

Comment: I have change it to string (this is the html) but not getting error on nonvalid Num. <input name="PhoneNumber" class="form-control  text-right text-box single-line" id="PhoneNumber" required="required" type="text" placeholder="Phone number" value="" data-val-required="number" data-val="true" data-val-regex-pattern="^0(([57]\d)|[23489])\s*-?\s*[2-9]\d{6}$" data-val-regex="Not valid phone ">

Comment: Remove `required = "required"` - you already have the `[Required]` attribute on your property.

Comment: <input name="PhoneNumber" class="form-control  text-right text-box single-line" id="PhoneNumber" type="text" placeholder="Phone number" value="" data-val-required="number" data-val="true" data-val-regex-pattern="^0(([57]\d)|[23489])\s*-?\s*[2-9]\d{6}$" data-val-regex="Not valid phone ">  No Diff.

Comment: When you attempt to submit with an invalid value, is the `input-validation-error` class name being added?

Comment: Befor any data and after any data its the same :<span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="PhoneNumber"></span>